# how to handle dynamic image gallery in angular

Tags: angular, assets, image-gallery

I have a webapp where there is a gallery, and there is the possibility of uploading new images for the gallery. The problem is that when I upload a new image to be able to view it in the gallery I have to recompile (you see the card of the image but not the image itself). This happens because the images are in the folder 'assets /' which is static in nature. I tried to put the images in the server folder and to change the url but the images are not displayed. Also I noticed that if the url is in full, for example '/ home / andrea / lavoro / angular / CarsMarketPlace / src / assets / CarsImages /' the images are not loaded, I have to set the url simply as' assets / CarsImages '. I believe that the images from the server folder are not displayed for the same reason. 
I get on lite-server log:

```
20.02.23 10:48:26 404 GET /home/andrea/lavoro/angular/CarsMarketPlace/server/CarsImages/audi_mod1_img1.jpg
```

but if I copy and paste the log link into the browser, I can see the image.
Anyone give me a solution to be able to view images from the server folder? Maybe there is some configuration to do in a json file ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a dynamic list of image paths and loop over it using NgFor. 
That way, when you upload an image, add its path to the list and it will update the gallery once loaded.

Comment: Thanks for interest but Maybe you didn't hit the crux of the problem. The real problem is that it gives me 404 error when trying to load the image but the url is correct.

Comment: Oh, in that case my only advice can be to write to log the current path, see that it runs where you think it runs...

Sorry